# Access violation when I declare a variable

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have hit a bit of a wall with some debugging. I have been getting two Access violation errors in completely unrelated parts of my program, neither of them I really understand. One of them occurs when I declare a new variable, in this case,

```
std::map<float, float> fMap;
```

I have checked that the name is not used anywhere else in the code, I'm not sure how that would be relevant but it's all I can think of. I think I have only ever managed to produce one of these when I do something stupid with a pointer. Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing this? The project is being compiled with Borland 6.

Thanks,

Comment: You're getting Access violations when you compile the code or when you run the code?

Comment: Declaration has nothing to do with the access violation. Write a small program where you can reproduce this behavior and post it in the question.

Comment: Can you provide a full but minimal program that replicates the error you're getting? something like, `#include` directives plus `int main(){std::map<float, float> fMap; return 0;}`? (Which works on my machine, btw)

Comment: Just the declaration of `fMap` causes issue?  What scope is the declaration in?  In particular, function, class member, or global?

Comment: I get the access violation when I run the code. I spent the last three hours wondering how on earth this can happen, I don't really know how STL works under the bonnet. However if I comment it out the error goes away, although it rather debilitates the program as the map would have gone on to do some rather important work. I'll see if I can reproduce it in a simple example.

Comment: @MerickOWA: No, he said - when he declares a variable. I think his editor is core dumping on him!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the declaration at hand: most likely, it is a delayed consequence of error that you made earlier. Some of the code that ran prior to hitting the map declaration has corrupted the heap in one way or another. Things that *could* potentially lead to a "delayed" crash are

- Releasing memory that has not been allocated to you
- Releasing memory several times
- Writing to outside the memory region that has been allocated to you

These errors may trigger a crash immediately, but they often do not: instead, a corrupted piece of some sensitive heap structure waits to be allocated to trigger a crash. When `std::map` allocates memory for its internals, it triggers the crash by requesting memory from a corrupted heap.

The best way to find out is to use a memory profiling tool. It should pinpoint the error to you at the time it happens, letting you address the problem instead of chasing its consequence.

Comment: If I comment out the map (and consequently some other stuff) the method executes without issue including the creation of a few other stl objects. That said this might explain the other seemingly non-sensical access violation.

Comment: @Bowler Whether or not you see the crash depends on the size of the allocation, and the number of items being allocated. That is why the timing of the crash is somewhat arbitrary, especially in concurrent environments. Using a memory profiler should clear everything up.

Comment: Spot on. For reasons that I don't understand an object I had new'd seemed to be causing the problem. Making it a pointer in the first place was probably the wrong choice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats as keys for std::maps, the comparison operators don't work very well with floating points. Can you give me some more detail of the other errors?

Comment: "Don't use floats as keys..." may be an over-generalization.  See the many other related questions on SO. But it is certainly a valid point to question. Using floats as keys is rarely the right thing to do. When you really do need floats as keys, you usually also need a custom compare function and/or other special features in the calling code.  The OP asking the original "access violation" question is most likely not dealing with one of these special cases.

Comment: Since when?  The `<` operator on `float` defines the required ordering relationship (as least as long as there are no NaNs).  It may not be appropriate to use `float` as a key (but that depends on the provenance of the floats), but it certainly doesn't create any undefined behavior nor should it lead to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a result of an earlier error—something you did
which is undefined behavior, probably something to do with an invalid
pointer or reference, or misusing a pointer.  One of the most frequence
reasons is writing beyond the end of an allocated block or writing
through a dangling pointer (memory already deleted).  This can often be 
very hidden, e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
int& r = v[0];
v.push_back(2);
r = 0;
```

Adding or removing elements from a container can, under certain
circumstances (which depend on the type of the container) invalidate all
references or pointers to elements in the container.

Back in the days of C, one of the most common causes was allocating
`strlen` bytes, then `strcpy`ing into them.  If you're using modern C++,
you're never allocating arrays of anything, and the most common reason
is probably insertions into a container invalidating a pointer, a
reference or an iterator that is still being used.  Using a debug
version of the library will catch the problems with iterators; tools
like valgrind will usually catch the problems with pointers and
references.  You should be using both (along with good test
suites—neither will catch errors which don't occur in the test
cases).